# Select command in Servicestack.Ormlite is difference in 4.0.54 and 4.0.56 when I profiling

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

When I profiling the same select command:

4.0.50:

```
SELECT "CustomerID", "CustomerCode", "CustomerName"
FROM "dbo"."Customer"
WHERE "CustomerCode" In ('871110000','864483025')
```

4.0.56:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT "CustomerID", "CustomerCode", "CustomerName" 
FROM "Customer"
WHERE "CustomerCode" In (@0,@1)',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ,@1 nvarchar(max) ',@0=N'871110000',@1=N'864483025'
```

Why does SS has this change?

My CustomerCode is Varchar field but generated command is Nvarchar and dont use my Index so the command very slow.

How can i fix that?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide the surrounding code on this. In particular, how are you generating the collection of `CustomerCode` values to pass into the SQL Statement? How are you calling the `Select` command? More details will help here.

Additionally, it appears that you changed the name of your class from `Customer` to `CoreCustomer`. Is this on purpose?

Comment: Thank you, Tony. When I have posted the question I edited the Core_Customer to Customer but forgot in the second phrase.
Here is my code:

  using (var db = _connectionFactory.Open())
            {                
                var customer = db.Select<Customer>(p => customerCodesList.Contains(p.CustomerCode));               
            }

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to find a way to set the IN Parameter types, so we will choose the nuclear option.

If you are still using 4.0.56, you can add the following line to your application startup.

`OrmLiteConfig.UseParameterizeSqlExpressions = false;`

This will make ORMLite use the "old" way that it created SQL queries with parameters (the way it did pre-4.0.54). Note that this property is set as deprecated, so if you've upgraded ORMLite you'll have to determine if it still exists.

Comment: Great! Comment back if anything needs clarified, or choose this answer as accepted if it works out for you!